# InvalidOperationException unhandeled . it does not show any errors while running, but shows this while executing the command

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

you can get screenshot here"https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzeqK.png"

```
namespace session
{
    public class Broker
    {
        OleDbConnection connection;
        OleDbCommand command;

        private void connectto()
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Tech Geek\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WindowsFormsApplication8\Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
            command = new OleDbCommand();
        }

        public Broker()
        {
            connectto();
        }

        public void Insert(person p)
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO n_account(customerid, sponsorname, applicantname, fatherhusbandsname, nomineename, applicantdob, nomineedob, houseno, state, district, tehsil, post,city, pincode, contactno, idprooftype, addressprooftype, panno, ammount, months, maturitydate, maturityfund, lastpremiumpaid) VALUES('" + p.Customerid + "','" + p.Sponsorname + "','" + p.Applicantname + "','" + p.Fatherhusbandsname + "','" + p.Nomineename + "','" + p.Applicantdob + "','" + p.Nomineedob + "','" + p.Houseno + "','" + p.State + "','" + p.District + "','" + p.Tehsil + "','" + p.Post + "','" + p.City + "','" + p.Pincode + "','" + p.Contactno + "','" + p.Idprooftype + "','" + p.Addressprooftype + "','" + p.Panno + "','" + p.Ammount + "','" + p.Months + "','" + p.Maturitydate + "','" + p.Maturityfund + "','" + p.Lastpremiumpaid + "')";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Please help

I have also attached a screenshot of the error.  I used the same code in another program - that is working fine.  I do not know what happened with this one.

Comment: I can't see your image and you have spelling mistakes and grammatical errors that hide what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error indicates you have not set the connection property for the command.

before this line

```
connection.Open();
```

add

```
command.Connection = connection;
```

Comment: can somebody help me with teamviewr please having many issues

Comment: can u give me online tutions i can also pay fees please.

Comment: @user2783278 I am not a tutor, but I might be to provide a few pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the OleDbCommand Command property wasn't initialized.

Make sure you set the command property or use the appropriate constructor, e.g.

`conn.Open();
  cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn);`

Comment: sir i am using acess database